# Area under curve of Sentinel-2 time-series using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am working with Sentinel-2 time series in Google Earth Engine (GEE). I would like to calculate the area under the curve (AUC) defined by a smoothed time series using a Savizky-Golay filter.

The method should compute the integral on the interval defined by the start and the end of the time series [x=a, x=b] (see Image) or other method to compute an approximation of the AUC. Any ideas on how to approach this? Or, how can I get the function which defines the curve?

[image]

This is my code to get the smoothed time series. Source: https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/end-to-end-gee.html

```
// Aplying Savitzky-Golay Filter on a NDVI Time-Series
// This script uses the OEEL library to apply a 
// Savitzky-Golay filter on a imagecollection

// We require a regularly-spaced time-series without
// any masked pixels. So this script applies
// linear interpolation to created regularly spaced images
// from the original time-series

// Step-1: Prepare a NDVI Time-Series
// Step-2: Create an empty Time-Series with images at n days
// Step-3: Use Joins to find before/after images
// Step-4: Apply linear interpolation to fill each image
// Step-5: Apply Savitzky-Golay filter
// Step-6: Visualize the results

//##############################################################
// Step-1: Prepare a NDVI time-series
//##############################################################

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2"); 
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
  [82.60642647743225, 27.16350437805251],
  [82.60984897613525, 27.1618529901377],
  [82.61088967323303, 27.163695288375266],
  [82.60757446289062, 27.16517483230927]
]]);
Map.addLayer(geometry, {color: 'red'}, 'Farm')
Map.centerObject(geometry)

var startDate = ee.Date('2017-01-01')
var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year')

var filtered = s2
  .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))

// Write a function for Cloud masking
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60')
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
  return image.updateMask(mask)//.divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
}

var filtered = filtered.map(maskS2clouds)


// Write a function that computes NDVI for an image and adds it as a band
function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).toFloat().rename('ndvi');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}


// Map the function over the collection
var withNdvi = filtered.map(addNDVI);

// Select 'ndvi' band
var ndviCol = withNdvi.select('ndvi')
print('Original Collection', ndviCol)

//##############################################################
// Step-2: Create an empty Time-Series with images at n days
//##############################################################

// Select the interval. We will have 1 image every n days
var n = 5;
var totalDays = endDate.difference(startDate, 'day');
var daysToInterpolate = ee.List.sequence(1, totalDays, n)

var initImages = daysToInterpolate.map(function(day) {
  var image = ee.Image().rename('ndvi').toFloat().set({
    'system:index': ee.Number(day).format('%d'),
    'system:time_start': startDate.advance(day, 'day').millis(),
    // Set a property so we can identify interpolated images
    'type': 'interpolated'
  })
  return image
})

var initCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(initImages)
print('Empty Collection', initCol)

//##############################################################
// Step-3: Use Joins to find before/after images
//##############################################################

// Merge empty collection with the original collection so we can
// find images to interpolate from
var mergedCol = ndviCol.merge(initCol)

var mergedCol = mergedCol.map(function(image) {
  var timeImage = image.metadata('system:time_start').rename('timestamp')
  var timeImageMasked = timeImage.updateMask(image.mask().select(0))
  return image.addBands(timeImageMasked)
})

// Specify the time-window
// Set it so that we have at least 1 non-cloudy image in the period
var days = 60
var millis = ee.Number(days).multiply(1000*60*60*24)

var maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: millis,
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

var lessEqFilter = ee.Filter.lessThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})


var greaterEqFilter = ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})


var filter1 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, lessEqFilter)
var join1 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'after',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: false})
  
var join1Result = join1.apply({
  primary: mergedCol,
  secondary: mergedCol,
  condition: filter1
})

var filter2 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, greaterEqFilter)

var join2 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'before',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: true})
  
var join2Result = join2.apply({
  primary: join1Result,
  secondary: join1Result,
  condition: filter2
})

//##############################################################
// Step-4: Apply linear interpolation to fill each image
//##############################################################

// Once the joins are done, we don't need original NDVI images
// We keep only the blank images which now have matching NDVI images
// as properties
var filtered = join2Result.filter(ee.Filter.eq('type', 'interpolated'))

// Interpolatinon function
function interpolateImages(image) {
  var image = ee.Image(image)

  var beforeImages = ee.List(image.get('before'))
  var beforeMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(beforeImages).mosaic()
  var afterImages = ee.List(image.get('after'))
  var afterMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(afterImages).mosaic()

  var t1 = beforeMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t1')
  var t2 = afterMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t2')

  var t = image.metadata('system:time_start').rename('t')

  var timeImage = ee.Image.cat([t1, t2, t])

  var timeRatio = timeImage.expression('(t - t1) / (t2 - t1)', {
    't': timeImage.select('t'),
    't1': timeImage.select('t1'),
    't2': timeImage.select('t2'),
  })

  var interpolated = beforeMosaic
    .add((afterMosaic.subtract(beforeMosaic).multiply(timeRatio)))
  var result = image.unmask(interpolated)
  return result.copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
}

var interpolatedCol = ee.ImageCollection(
  filtered.map(interpolateImages)).select('ndvi')
print('Interpolated Collection', interpolatedCol)

//##############################################################
// Step-5: Apply Savitzky-Golay filter
//##############################################################

var oeel=require('users/OEEL/lib:loadAll');
// https://www.open-geocomputing.org/OpenEarthEngineLibrary/#.ImageCollection.SavatskyGolayFilter

// Use the same maxDiffFilter we used earlier
var maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: millis,
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

// Use the default distanceFunction
var distanceFunction = function(infromedImage, estimationImage) {
  return ee.Image.constant(
      ee.Number(infromedImage.get('system:time_start'))
      .subtract(
        ee.Number(estimationImage.get('system:time_start')))
        );
  }

// Apply smoothing of order=3
var order = 3;
var smoothed = oeel.ImageCollection.SavatskyGolayFilter(
  interpolatedCol, 
  maxDiffFilter,
  distanceFunction,
  order)

// Select the d_0_ndvi band and rename it
var smoothed = smoothed.select(['d_0_ndvi'], ['smoothed'])

//##############################################################
// Step-6: Visualize the results
//##############################################################

// Chart the time-series at a single location
var title = 'Savitsky-Golay smoothing' +
  '(order = '+ order + ', window_size = ' + days + ')'

// Plot the original and fitted NDVI time-series
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: ndviCol.merge(smoothed),
  region: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 20
}).setOptions({
      lineWidth: 1,
      title: title,
      interpolateNulls: true,
      vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
      hAxis: {title: '', format: 'YYYY-MMM'},
      series: {
        0: {color: 'blue', lineWidth: 1, 
          lineDashStyle: [1, 1], pointSize: 1,
          }, // Original NDVI
        1: {color: 'red', lineWidth: 2 }, // Smoothed NDVI
      },

    })
print(chart)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most expedite way to do that is by using Simpson method with **smoothed** values obtained of downloaded CSV chart. It can be accessed with click in the button inside red square of following picture.

[image]

and the download CSV button appears as follows:

[image]

Smoothed values (73; as number of elements in smoothed Image Collection) from CSV file were converted in a list variable at the beginning of following code. As these values have a spacing of 5 days then, the value of h is 5 in following lines.

```
//simpson method

var smoothed = [0.3,0.317,0.379,0.452,0.519,0.573,0.61,0.629,0.628,0.613,0.587,0.556,0.521,
                0.485,0.448,0.411,0.363,0.317,0.273,0.227,0.185,0.148,0.12,0.103,0.093,0.086,
                0.082,0.079,0.076,0.071,0.066,0.059,0.053,0.051,0.052,0.057,0.067,0.081,0.103,
                0.129,0.165,0.209,0.252,0.292,0.328,0.363,0.398,0.431,0.459,0.479,0.491,0.494,
                0.488,0.475,0.457,0.43,0.397,0.357,0.316,0.285,0.254,0.227,0.206,0.189,0.181,
                0.171,0.157,0.151,0.162,0.192,0.239,0.302,0.397];

var n = ee.List(smoothed).size().subtract(1);
print("number of values", n.add(1));

var h = 5;

var serverList = ee.List.sequence(1, n, 2);

print(serverList);

serverList = serverList.map(function(n){

  n = ee.Number(n).int();
  var n_sub = n.subtract(1);
  var n_add = n.add(1);

  var sum = ee.Number.expression(
      '(h/3)*(v1 + 4*v2 + v3)',{
      'v1': ee.List(smoothed).get(n_sub),
      'v2': ee.List(smoothed).get(n),
      'v3': ee.List(smoothed).get(n_add),
      'h': h
      }
    );
  
  return sum;
  
});

var area = ee.List(serverList).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());

print("area under the curve (AUC)", ee.Number(area).format('%.2f'));
```

After running [above code](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/c96eb020f9a0bcf4b9a1807716b27e84) in GEE code editor, result is printed in Console Tab as:

```
number of values
73
List (36 elements)
area under the curve (AUC)
105.02
```

I corroborated that this code works as expected by using the values from [here](https://joseguerreroa.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/integracion-numerica-c-linux/) (article in Spanish) where result (h = 1) corresponds an area of 72 (parabola X<sup>2</sup> between [0,6] ).

Comment: The optimal solution is yours, not mine ( applying this method automatically without no needs to download the .CSV). You didn't know about numerical methods of integration for obtaining area under the curve of Sentinel-2 time-serie; the main subject of your question.  Remember that in this site is one question by question.

Comment: I edited my question for deleting code with client-side for-loop. Now, it uses server-side mapping. Execution is much faster than for-loop version.

Comment: This solution fails when the number of smoothed values is an even number. How can I should fix this?

Comment: @sermomon Sorry, just now I watch your comment.  First, calculate for n-1 points (odd number of points). Afterward, add the last area as a single trapezoid.  You should modify slightly the code for that.